# how to apply neon effects on container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to add to come up with the following UI in flutter.
I added two containers with Stack for the desired locations on the screen.
However, I couldn't make them shine and look like the following image.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420822/how-to-add-a-neon-glow-effect-to-an-widget-border-shadow?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the flutter BackdropFilter application and properties, and try to have this over the coloured spots.

[BackdropFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)

You could also look at the Glassmorphism package to achieve a similar effect.

[Glassmorphism](https://pub.dev/documentation/glassmorphism/latest/)